# Reset Password through OTP

Tags: java, spring

I'am developing Api's for Reset Password :-

1st One :- validating email or phone and Send OTP.

2nd One :- validating OTP.

3rd One :- Reset Password.

Problems:-

1.How I can maintain OTP at api side to validate it.
2.If a person directly hit my reset password Api,then he/she could change password, which is a security breach.

Please answer!!!Thanx in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1.How I can maintain OTP at api side to validate it.

OTP for password reset should be random, time limited and bound to a username. So yes, you need to maintain the OTPs persistently

Option one -  you either build a database where you store the generated OTPs with their validity.

Option two - you can generate OTP in form of signed jwt so the  validation algorithm just validates the timestamp and signature (this OTP password is longer, so feasible only for email)

> 2.If a person directly hit my reset password Api,then he/she could change password, which is a security breach.

There is no point of exposing a separate validation service. The reset service itself should validate the otp and reset the password or not (as one operation)